# Targeting 1 element not all jquery js

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have few spans in a grid and I have a small problem. When I hover 1 element all hidden spans activated. I would like to activate only one hovered.

```
                $('.tried-it').live('mouseover', function(){
                    $('.tried-times').fadeIn(500).addClass("show-me").removeClass("hide-me");
                });

                $(".tried-it").live('mouseout',function() { 
                    $(".tried-times").fadeOut(500).removeClass("show-me").addClass("hide-me");
                    return false; 

                });
```

and spans:

```
<span class="tried-times hide-me">30 times</span>
<span class="tried-it"></span>
```

Comment: is that your span structure throughout your page?

Comment: yes.. this is a span stucture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a strange way to structure your elements, but if they are placed just one after the other, I'd do something like:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).prev('.tried-times').addClass("show-me")
                                    .removeClass("hide-me")
                                    .fadeIn(500);
    },
    mouseleave: function() { 
        $(this).prev('.tried-times').fadeOut(500)
                                    .removeClass("show-me")
                                    .addClass("hide-me");
    }
}, '.tried-it');​
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fbxTK/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but No luck.

Comment: @user1174849 - I added a fiddle, maybe that makes it easier to understand how it was intented to work ?

Comment: I have seen your fiddle. it works within fiddle. But in my content it doesnt :(

Comment: I think i forgot to mention 2 classes I have:
.hide-me{display:none;}
.show-me{display:block;}

Comment: Why would you need those classes? jQuery's fadeIn/fadeOut sets the display to block/none, no need to do it once more, and that's probably why you are having problems in the first place. Remove those, hide the elements initially, and just fade them in and out on mouseenter/leave.

Comment: I have removed them. But with your fiddle I'm getting: TypeError: $(document).on is not a function
[Break On This Error] 
}, '.tried-it');
Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1174849 - Without the classes you could do this much simpler, have a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fbxTK/1/)---

Comment: I had to use  hercules = jQuery.noConflict(true); because I have other library And now everything works!  Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, operating on the instance of the element that fired the event only. Notice that the selector is `$(this)` instead of `$('.tried-times')`:

```
$('.tried-it').live('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(500).addClass("show-me").removeClass("hide-me");
});

$(".tried-it").live('mouseout',function() { 
    $(this).fadeOut(500).removeClass("show-me").addClass("hide-me");
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: On mouse over nothing happens :). On mouse out elements are invisible:) cool function, but that is not what I wanted to achieve . I have tried before: $(".tried-it").hover(function() {       $(this).parents().fadeIn(500).addClass("show-me").removeClass("hide-me"); });